# How can I make this green colour come from bottom in place of coming from right

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is a timer animation made using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and a little bit of jQuery.

```js
var value = 0;
var pos = 0;
var progressHidden = false;
var delay = 40;
var progressEL = $('progress');
var timer = setInterval(progress, 100);

function progress() {
  value++;

  if (value < 59) {
    progressEL.val(value);
    pos = 1 - (value / 85);
  } else if (value < (delay + 60)) {
    progressEL.val(59);
    pos = 0;
  } else {
    value = 0;
  }
  progressEL.css('background-position', '0' + pos + 'em');
  if (!progressHidden && value >= 60) {
    progressEL.addClass("hidden");
    progressHidden = true;
  } else if (progressHidden && value < 60) {
    progressEL.val(0);
    progressEL.removeClass("hidden");
    progressHidden = false;
  }
}
```

```css
progress {
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 2.3em;
  height: 1.8em;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 200px;
  transition: height 0.2s;
}

progress.hidden {
  height: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

progress::before {
  content: attr(value);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.70em;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.2);
  background: linear-gradient( hsl(118, 97%, 50%), hsl(118, 97%, 50%), hsl(118, 97%, 50%) 90%) no-repeat center;
  background-position: inherit;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar,
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: transparent;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<progress max="99"></progress>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
```

I need the green colour to fill the whole letter as you can see a little gap remains in there and I also want the green colour to come from bottom. You just have to adjust the position value of background somehow I guess.
This is the entire code please provide me with the solution.

Comment: Green color, letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the your code a little. I used CSS variable for `background-size` and I set `0%` as default value. And I changed the background-size with value.

```js
var value = 0;
var pos = 0;
var progressHidden = false;
var delay = 40;
var progressEL = $('progress');
var timer = setInterval(progress, 100);

function progress() {
  value++;

  if (value < 59) {
    progressEL.val(value);
    pos = 1 - (value / 85);
  } else if (value < (delay + 60)) {
    progressEL.val(59);
    pos = 0;
  } else {
    value = 0;
  }
  
  progressEL[0].style.setProperty("--size", value + "%");
  
  if (!progressHidden && value >= 60) {
    progressEL.addClass("hidden");
    progressHidden = true;
  } else if (progressHidden && value < 60) {
    progressEL.val(0);
    progressEL.removeClass("hidden");
    progressHidden = false;
  }
}
```

```css
progress {
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 2.3em;
  height: 1.8em;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 200px;
  transition: height 0.2s;
}

progress.hidden {
  height: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

progress::before {
  content: attr(value);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.70em;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.2);
  background: linear-gradient( hsl(118, 97%, 50%), hsl(118, 97%, 50%), hsl(118, 97%, 50%) 90%) no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 100% var(--size, 0%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar,
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: transparent;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<progress max="99"></progress>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
```